# Getting an error when using replaceOccuranceOfString function

Tags: iphone, replace, nsmutablestring, nscfstring

`[str replaceOccurrencesOfString: withString: options: range:`

`[str replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"!~" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0,str.length)]`

I am using this function to replace ' symbol in my `NSMutableString` with !~ symbol so that I can store that string into database. Its working fine when I stored it into database, but at the time of retrieving and convert it back using same function it showing me error like.

**Error**
`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to mutate immutable object with replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:'`

Here, `str` is of `NSMutableString` type. I checked for its type `[str class]` its converts to `NSCFString` don't know why its changing? I also try to convert it to `NSMutableString`, but its not converting. I am trying for it for so many times in some other ways, but its working fine with all other places, only in my one view controller, it showing me this.

Any guesses where's I am doing wrong?

Comment: try to allocate the str variable before using it.

Comment: @RamaRao, I tried for it! Its not working.

Comment: have u tried like this NSString *str = [[[NSString alloc] init] retain];

Comment: How are you declaring and setting `str` in your code? Where is the text in the string coming from (what other parts of your code) and is it mutable then?

Comment: [str isKindOfClass:[NSMutableString class]], check wether this statement is returning true or not, i suspect this issue is due to immutable only.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist, the string data of `VARCHAR` type coming from database, in format of `NSMutableDictionary`, I am accessing it like `str=[[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictionary valueForKey:@"title"]];`

Comment: @RIP, As I written in my question when I checked for its class type, it converts to `NSCFString`

Comment: @RamaRao, thank you! I again try for it! and it get solved:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show how you are converting the immutable from the data base to a mutable string. Just doing `NSMutableString *mstr = str;` isn't enough, you'd need to use `NSMutableString *mstr = [NSMutableString stringWithString:str];`.

Because the returned string is immutable you might want to consider using `[NSString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]` instead of working with mutable strings.